# ansible conditions for modules parameters

Tags: ansible

Stack on this issue to make my code clear.

Example:

```
- name: task
  copy:
    src: "{{ 1 }}"
    dest: "{{ 2 }}"
```

As I can see in doc file module copy has parameter:
*remote_src: yes/no*

So my question is:

Is it possible to use this parameter depends on any condition I have in a single task block?

Something like:

```
- name: task
  copy:
    src: "{{ 1 }}"
    dest: "{{ 2 }}"
 if my_condition == 1
    remote_src: yes
 else
    remote_src: no
```

Tried if / when - but wanna see it in one task block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ternary](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8) filter

```
- name: task
  copy:
    src: "{{ 1 }}"
    dest: "{{ 2 }}"
    remote_src: "{{ (my_condition == 1)|ternary('yes', 'no') }}"
```

Comment: almost forgot about filters. Thank you!      Totally depends on syntax, so if someone needed use it like this:   remote_src: "{{ (my_condition == '1')|ternary('yes', 'no') }}"